# A variation on internally distributing a rails app

Tags: ruby

I have written a ruby service that I want to package and distribute internally to a specific environment (a standardized linux host). After digging around a bit for the best ways to create a distribution, I've come across a lot of blogs and answers here that recommend `bundler` and `gem` packaging as well as a lot of binary distribution options (e.g. `traveling-ruby`), but these all seem like a bit too much for a relatively simple service that will get deployed to a known environment. I want to create a distribution that doesn't require dependencies to be resolved at deploy time (e.g. `bundle install --deployment` is not the approach I want).

So with this in mind, is there an available framework that is commonly in use by ruby apps that would create a redistributable package with all dependencies included in it? I am currently doing this in 2 steps and wondering if there's a "better" ruby-way of doing it - something along the lines of `gem build ...` that creates dependency-inclusive archive?

```
# Assuming `bundle install` was run on developer workstation and there's a `Gemfile.lock`
$ bundle install --deployment
$ tar zcf ../my-app.tar.gz ./
```

`my-app.tar.gz` can now be distributed and if I have an executable to run it with, I can do so with `bundle exec bin/run` from within the directory after it's extracted. This a good approach?

I've seen a gem called `crate` that might be able to work....